# Handle SMTP events using C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I need to trigger a routine, when a new email is received on a smtp server.

I foun information about plug-in develpment for outlook but i figure pugins have to be installed in client.

Well, the only way that should work for me is cacthing theNEW_MAIL envet on smtp server using a Service.

Is that possible? Thanks.

I have to catch de new email when it is received.
Validate If has an attached file.
Validate file name,
if file name is correct
get the attached file and download to a file server...

Comment: There is no SMTP server as part of .Net framework. You need to specify more details what SMTP server you are using before this question can be answered. Showing what you've tried would be plus too.

Comment: I tried anything cause i have no idea. The only way to reach this functionality is using plug in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an script in the OutlookSession and applied as rule. 
There is a tutorial: [Apply rule.... has an attachment and run script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zlqm38ieP0k)

```
Public Sub Drc(emailItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim targetFolder As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim regxpr As String
    Dim fileType As String
    Dim iFrom As String
    iFrom = "******"
    Dim isubject As String

    isubject = emailItem.Subject
    If emailItem.Sender = iFrom And ValidateFileName(isubject) Then
    For Each objAtt In emailItem.Attachments
        fileType = Split(objAtt.DisplayName, ".")(1)
        targetFolder = "C:\TestCsvDirectory\ToProcess"
        If ValidateFileName(objAtt.DisplayName) And LCase(fileType) = "csv" Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile (targetFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName)
        End If

    Next
End If
```